# auto number in data grid view and access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I wanted to make a program using access database and make it auto number the rows but when I delete a row the order of the rows is incorrect and the program starts with the last row number

The deletion code I used:

```
Sub delete()
    Try

        If MsgBox("Are You Sure Delete This Record", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            conn.Open()
            Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Delete from MedicineDB Where ID=@ID", conn)
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtID.Text)
            i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
            If i > 0 Then
                MsgBox("Record Delete Success !", vbInformation)
            Else
                MsgBox("Failed", vbCritical)
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    conn.Close()
    loadingDatagridView()
    clear()
End Sub
```

that is the result:
[image]

Comment: Those numbers are not valid until you have saved the data to the database. That is when the database generates the IDs. Until then, they are only temporary values generated by the application. The fact that they are the same for the very first record(s) is just a coincidence. Even if you didn't delete anything it would still be the case. What if you did a filtered query to only get some of the records and then added one? What if you wanted to add one without retrieving any records first? The temp values can be used to maintain relationships in new data but must be replaced from the database.

Comment: One thing to note, probably nothing to do with the actual question.  _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtID.Text)_ will create a String parameter, you are much better off using Parameters.Add("@ID", _DBVarTypeHere_).Value = Int.Parse(txtID.Text).  Assuming of course that ID is an integer type in the DB